# Is there someway to sort a structure while passing it in a void function using pointers only?

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, struct

I'm trying to sort some random points and the distance of the points from a user input point (consider it to be (0,0) i.e. the origin) on an XY coordinate system in a sort function by using pointers, when I remove the points sorting code from the sort function then distance sorting is fine, but when I try to sort the points as well as the distance the code doesn't work. I know a similar question about sorting points has been asked but I know the logic I want to implement it using pointers only. Could someone help?

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct point {
    float x, y;
};

void sort();

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of points in the system:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    float d[n], xi, yi;
    struct point p[n];
    printf("\nEnter the X and Y coordinates of the points-\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the X coordinate of point %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &p[i].x);
        printf("Enter the Y coordinate of point %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &p[i].y);
    }
    
    printf("\nPoints entered are-\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d- (%0.2f,%0.2f)\n", i + 1, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter the X coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:");
    scanf("%f", &xi);
    printf("Enter the Y coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:");
    scanf("%f", &yi);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        d[i] = fabs(sqrt(pow(((p[i].x) - xi), 2) + pow(((p[i].y) - yi), 2)));
    }
    
    printf("\nDistance- ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%0.2f  ", d[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    sort(d);
    printf("\n\nSorted distance- ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%0.2f  ", d[i]);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d- (%0.2f,%0.2f)\n", i + 1, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
}

void sort(float *d, struct point *p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(d) / sizeof(float); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (sizeof(d) / sizeof(float)) - i; j++) {
            if (*(d + i) > *(d + i + j)) {
                float temp = *(d + i), pxtemp = (p + i)->x, pytemp = (p + i)->y;            
                *(d + i) = *(d + i + j);                                              
                *(d + i + j) = temp;
                /*(p + i)->x = (p + i + j)->x;
                (p + i + j)->x = pxtemp;
                (p + i)->y = (p + i + j)->y;
                (p + i + j)->y = pytemp;*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter the number of points in the system:2

Enter the X and Y coordinates of the points-
Enter the X coordinate of point 1: 5
Enter the Y coordinate of point 1: 6
Enter the X coordinate of point 2: 3
Enter the Y coordinate of point 2: 4

Points entered are-
1- (5.00,6.00)
2- (3.00,4.00)

Enter the X coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:0
Enter the Y coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:0

Distance- 7.81  5.00
```

Comment: You are calling your function with one parameter, but your function definition has two parameters. Your C compiler would have told you this if you had declared it with the correct prototype. — In fact, you should also compile with warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` on GCC and clang), because those warnings are helpful and will let you know about many other issues with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not pass `p` to the `sort` function.
- in this `sort` function, `sizeof(d) / sizeof(float)` does not evaluate to the number of entries in the array pointed to by `d` because `d` is just a pointer. You must pass the length of the arrays `n` as an extra argument.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
    float x, y;
};

void sort(float *d, struct point *p, int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (d[i] > d[i + 1]) {
                float temp = d[i];
                d[i] = d[i + 1];
                d[i + 1] = temp;
                struct point temp1 = p[i];
                p[i] = p[i + 1];
                p[i + 1] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of points in the system:");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1)
        return 1;
    float d[n], xi, yi;
    struct point p[n];
    printf("\nEnter the X and Y coordinates of the points-\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the X coordinate of point %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%f", &p[i].x) != 1)
            return 1;
        printf("Enter the Y coordinate of point %d: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%f", &p[i].y) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    
    printf("\nPoints entered are-\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d- (%0.2f,%0.2f)\n", i + 1, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter the X coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:");
    if (scanf("%f", &xi) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("Enter the Y coordinate of point from which distance is to be calculated:");
    if (scanf("%f", &yi) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // use hypot() to compute the distance between 2 points
        // it has better behavior than sqrt(dx2 + dy2) in corner cases.
        d[i] = hypot(p[i].x - xi, p[i].y - yi);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Distance- ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%0.2f  ", d[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    sort(d, p, n);

    printf("\n\nSorted distance- ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%0.2f  ", d[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d- (%0.2f,%0.2f)\n", i + 1, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on the point of hypot() behavior in corner cases.

Comment: @AshutoshYadav: when you compute **x² + y²** with **y** much smaller than **x**, the result is just **x²** and taking the square root gives **|x|**, whereas it should be closer to **|x| + |y|/2**. The standard `hypot()` function uses a different method to compute the distance for values of **x** and **y** that are too far apart in magnitude. It also handles the case where **x²** or **y²** would overflow or underflow.

Comment: Can't say that the indexes used in this `sort()` are really going to sort the elements of the arrays... Kinda like this is the reason why ~15 lines of hand-rolled code doesn't compete with a one-line call to a standard library function (which doesn't sort 'parallel arrays')... Fewer bugs... But, who actually reads this stuff that "just looks right"?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your function with all input parameters:

```
void sort(float *d,struct point *p);
```

And use both parameters when you call it:

```
sort(d, p);
```

Afterwards it seems to work fine, [test here](https://onlinegdb.com/1j39GMwIa).

Also, as Konrad Rudolph correctly pointed out, you need to pass the length of your array to the function, to use the correct length on your for-loops. They are also better readable afterwards.

```
void sort(float *d, struct point *p, int n);
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<n-i; j++)
```

Comment: It definitely doesn’t work fine after that, since the code has more bugs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If I enter '3, 5, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 0, 0' in that order (3 points, coordinates, root coordinate) it prints out the sorted distances and the sorted points. It may have bugs, but the points are sorted afterwards. Can you elaborate what is not working fine?

Comment: You got lucky, that's all. Check the loop headers, they compute the array length incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked it. Edit is out.

Comment: @izlin thanks, made all the corrections, working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

`"Could someone help?"`

Why do you have, and try to maintain, two "parallel" arrays?
One for x,y and one for a calculated distance.
Then try to keep their elements together when sorting and printing.

```
struct point {
    float x, y;
    float d;
};
```

Wouldn't that solve a lot of your problems?

You might even be able to pass the array full of these things to the standard library function `qsort()` to have it do the heavy lifting. (You'd have to comment out or remove your own `sort()` function, of course.)

Why make life harder than it already is?

---

**EDIT:**
Here are some fragments of code (and pseudocode) that you might find useful.

```
typedef struct {
    float x, y; // rect co-ord's
    float d; // calc'd distance from user co-ord
} xyd_t; // x,y and distance type


int cmpDist( const void *a1, const void *a2 ) { return ((xyd_t*)a)->d - ((xyd_t*)b)->d; }

xyd_t arr[ 20 ]; // 20 only as example
memset( arr, 0, sizeof arr ); // initialise all to zero

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    arr[ i ].x = /* value */
    arr[ i ].y = /* value */
}

xyd_t user = { 37.5, 53.2, /* don't care */ };

calcDist( user, arr );

qsort( arr, n, sizeof arr[0], cmpDist );

for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    print i, arr[i].d; // distance
```

---

**EDIT2:**
It's bothersome that some SO answers are accepted even though they are flawed, while others are pretty much overlooked for whatever reason.

I've implemented the recommendations above and extended the OP code somewhat (as a toy project). Here, one 'reference point' is "entered" followed by 4 other x,y coordinates. These are set up in the source to avoid the hassle of re-typing or arcane input redirections. Easy to revert to a user interface.

Additions to the code extend its capability. Most importantly, the main body is abbreviated, a reliable sort routine is used, and... well... just some plain fun with 'bearings' from the reference point. It's a "code dump" because learning comes from figuring things out for oneself. This code points the way. (Thank you to @Chqrlie for some better trig math.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define tau 6.283185307179586476925286766559

typedef struct { double x, y, m; int a; } xyd_t;

int nrml( int deg ) {
    while( deg < 0 ) deg += 360;
    while( deg >= 360 ) deg -= 360;
    return deg;
}

char *compassRose( int deg, char *buf ) {
    char *pts =
        "N\0\0\0\0NNNE\0NNE\0\0ENNE\0NE\0\0\0NENE\0ENE\0\0EENE\0"
        "E\0\0\0\0EESE\0ESE\0\0SESE\0SE\0\0\0ESSE\0SSE\0\0SSSE\0"
        "S\0\0\0\0SSSW\0SSW\0\0WSSW\0SW\0\0\0WWSW\0WSW\0\0WWSW\0"
        "W\0\0\0\0WWNW\0WNW\0\0NWNW\0NW\0\0\0WNNW\0NNW\0\0NNNW\0"
        "N\0\0\0\0";
    int ind = int( (nrml( deg ) + (360.0/32.0)/2.0)*(32.0/360.0) );
    return (char*)memcpy( buf, pts + ind*5, 5 );
}

int nearToFar( const void *a1, const void *a2 ) { return ((xyd_t*)a1)->m > ((xyd_t*)a2)->m; }
int farToNear( const void *a1, const void *a2 ) { return ((xyd_t*)a2)->m > ((xyd_t*)a1)->m; }
int ccw( const void *a1, const void *a2 ) { return nrml(((xyd_t*)a2)->a) > nrml(((xyd_t*)a1)->a); }

void show( char *title, xyd_t *p, int n ) {
    char buf[ 4 + 1 ];
    puts( title );
    for( int i = 0; i < n; i++, p++ )
        printf( "(%0.2lf,%0.2lf) %0.2lf @ %d deg %s\n", p->x, p->y, p->m, p->a, compassRose(p->a, buf) );
}

void main() {
    int i, n;

//  printf( "Number of points including ref point: " );
//  scanf( "%d", &n );
    /* omitting test for success */

//  xyd_t pt[ n ];

    n = 5;
    xyd_t pt[ 1 + 4 ] = {
        { 12, 12, },
        { 15, 15, },
        {  7, 17, },
        {  6,  6, },
        { 16,  8, },
    };

    puts( "\nX and Y coordinates of the points, Ref Pt first-" );

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        printf( "\n#%d - X (space) Y coordinates: ", i );
//      scanf( "%lf%lf", &pt[i].x, &pt[i].y );
        /* omitting test for success */

        if( i ) {
            double deltaX = pt[i].x - pt[0].x;
            double deltaY = pt[i].y - pt[0].y;
            pt[i].m = hypot( deltaX, deltaY );
            pt[i].a = (int)(atan2( deltaX, deltaY )*360/tau)%360;
        }
    }

    show( "\n As entered:", pt, n );

    qsort( pt, n, sizeof xyd_t, nearToFar );
    show( "\n Sorted near to far:", pt, n );

    qsort( pt, n, sizeof xyd_t, farToNear );
    show( "\n Sorted far to near:", pt, n );

    qsort( pt, n, sizeof xyd_t, ccw );
    show( "\n Sorted counter-clockwise from North:", pt, n );
}
```

```
X and Y coordinates of the points, Ref Pt first-

#0 - X (space) Y coordinates: // prompts appear, but input data hardwired
#1 - X (space) Y coordinates:
#2 - X (space) Y coordinates:
#3 - X (space) Y coordinates:
#4 - X (space) Y coordinates:
 As entered:
(12.00,12.00) 0.00 @ 0 deg N
(15.00,15.00) 4.24 @ 45 deg NE
(7.00,17.00) 7.07 @ -45 deg NW
(6.00,6.00) 8.49 @ -135 deg SW
(16.00,8.00) 5.66 @ 135 deg SE

 Sorted near to far:
(12.00,12.00) 0.00 @ 0 deg N
(15.00,15.00) 4.24 @ 45 deg NE
(16.00,8.00) 5.66 @ 135 deg SE
(7.00,17.00) 7.07 @ -45 deg NW
(6.00,6.00) 8.49 @ -135 deg SW

 Sorted far to near:
(6.00,6.00) 8.49 @ -135 deg SW
(7.00,17.00) 7.07 @ -45 deg NW
(16.00,8.00) 5.66 @ 135 deg SE
(15.00,15.00) 4.24 @ 45 deg NE
(12.00,12.00) 0.00 @ 0 deg N

 Sorted counter-clockwise from North:
(7.00,17.00) 7.07 @ -45 deg NW
(6.00,6.00) 8.49 @ -135 deg SW
(16.00,8.00) 5.66 @ 135 deg SE
(15.00,15.00) 4.24 @ 45 deg NE
(12.00,12.00) 0.00 @ 0 deg N
```

Comment: 'Why do you have, and try to maintain, two "parallel" arrays?' -- because points don't have a length. By every common definition, points only have coordinates.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Just trying to retain connection to the OP code... Pick a different name. Pick "Sally" because sallies are journeys from a point going for some distance... Don't mess with me today, please... (PS: never heard of "rectangular coordinates", then? They don't have an 'x,y'... Wanna complain about that, too?)

Comment: @KonradRudolph correction: s/rectangular/polar/... As I say, it's been a bit of a day, today... My apologies for my mistake...

Comment: @Fe2O3  adding member "d" in the structure would indeed solve a lot of issues, especially maintaining 2 parallel arrays, thanks for the insight, will try and implement it.

Comment: @AshutoshYadav If you've found one of the offered answers acceptable, you might consider giving it a 'tick' to indicate that there is a useful response to your question.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Polar coordinates are still *coordinates* (i.e. not coord + length). And I'm not trying to mess with you, my comment was entirely genuine: please don't cram unsuitable data into a data type just because it makes a function simpler. Defining *suitable* data types is obviously great, but *they need to make sense*, otherwise they make code harder to read. And having two separate but associated arrays of data (as in OP's case) is a common and well established pattern, there's no inherent issue with that (but encapsulating them into a struct in turn would be beneficial).

Comment: @KonradRudolph While you are correct in your explanation of "points", the task at hand is less concerned with holding true to a dictionary definition and more concerned with a programming challenge that should be solved with clear concise code. McDonalds puts food(?!) orders in containers called 'bags' because bags serve the purpose of both the business and the customer. To juggle a burger, shake and fries AND the car keys is likely to make a big mess... Better to get the job done simply than adhere to some stricture for the sake of... well... what? "Adherence to a stricture?" Pashaw!!!

Comment: (ctd:) In the case of this OP, 'bundling' the calc'd distance to a ref point WITH each arbitrary point of the array _just makes sense_... It gets the job done AND facilitates using a proven library sort function instead of problematic _hand-rolled_ version. Other coders will appreciate being able to recognise (and trust) the sort operation... To adhere to a 'purity' (separation of a "point" struct from its 'distance' value) for this kind of data would make the code _less_ trustworthy, imho...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I’m afraid you’re still missing my point. I’m not concerned with any kind of conceptual purity (which, if I understand you correctly, is what you think) but with *readable code*. Mixing data willy-nilly inside a McDonald’s bag leads to an unmaintainable mess. Ketchup all over your functions, if you will. **But**: I do strongly agree with you about the reuse of library functions, *where possible* (but in that case, use, to keep code readable, use nested data types, don’t flatten them), but these are simply not always suitable (especially not with Data-Oriented Design).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think our debate is coming at the same problem but from opposite sides. You've wrestled with "stew pot" data structures (everything in one pot) while I've seen trivial structs nested 5 levels deep "to maintain separation". Ill conceived and implemented, either approach serves only to make code muddy. If the OP had 12 other 'meta data' elements packed into a struct instance, then, yes!, keeping the x,y clearly separate would definitely be better practice. If not, then this "simple" version is easy to comprehend. I think we're both calling-out for the same thing. "Clarity" `:-)`

Comment: @KonradRudolph The OP has claimed their privilege to choose a different answer as their favourite (and, amazing... 3xUV there as I type this.) NOW, check the indexes used in the "hand rolled" sort function of that answer (perhaps checking the answer's edit history.) Anyone (especially me!) can make a mistake. This is more my experience of bad code. Reams of code dealing with "unbundled, parallel" objects burying bugs in the sheer verbosity of the code... sigh...